# Ember Data: Persist fields not in model

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am developing an Ember application for an existing API. This API allows any arbitrary fields in the JSON payload, and will save all of them.
When defining models in Ember I cannot anticipate all the fields that may be used. Unfortunately, any update to a model means that these fields will be lost.
I'm looking for a solution that will persist fields that were retrieved by the API but not defined in the model.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a model with an ember data attribute without a type.
Then you would store your objects with arbitrary keys at this attribute.

```
export default Model.extend({
  data: attr()
});
```

This way, you can set anything at this prop including entire objects, i.e. `model.set('data', /* anything */)` and it will be stored in ember data.

Comment: Works well in conjunction with a custom serializer.

Comment: Glad it helped out. Ember and especially ember data sometimes requires hacking around when their strict opinions don't match an api in the wild.